# Apply a request action foreach data angular 2

Tags: angular

In angular 2, I want to dispatch a request for multiple data.
For example I have some user data (2 ids) and want to apply a request for every id.
My code:

```
handleOnBulkAction(actionId) {
  const dataUser = this.userState.bulkList.map((userId) => {
    return {
      item: userId,
    };
  });
  this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        dataUser.forEach(user => {
          console.log(user); //it return the id
          this.store.dispatch(new user.DeleteAction({
              user: user.item,
              organisationId: this.organisationId
          }));
        });
      }
      this.dialogRef = null;
  });
  return;
}
```

And it gives the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: user.DeleteAction is not a constructor
```

Do you have any idea?

EDIT:
actions/user.ts

```
export class DeleteAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.DELETE;

  constructor(public payload: any) {
  }
}
```

effects:

```
@Effect()
delete$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
.ofType(user.ActionTypes.DELETE)
.map(toPayload)
.switchMap((args) => {
  return this.userService.deleteUser(args.user)
    .concatMap(response => [
      new user.DeleteSuccessAction(args.user),
      new organisation.FetchOneAction(args.organisationId)
    ])
    .catch((error) => [
      new layout.HideLoadingAction(),
      new user.ChangeStatusErrorAction(error)
    ]);
});
```

service:

```
 public deleteUser(user) {
  return this.http.delete(`${this.userApi}/${user.id}`, {
    withCredentials: true,
  }).map(() => {
   }).catch(this.errorService.handleError);
 }
```

Comment: I assume that `DeleteAction` is class. So how does it look like?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Why `new user.DeleteAction(...)` and not only `new DeleteAction(...)`?

Comment: Hm..yeah, much better, it compiles now but if I choose 2 users to delete, it deletes only the second..